# Apply / merge image difference to another image?

Tags: java, image-processing, aforge

I have 2 images with a slight difference.

image1:

[image]

image2:

[image]

I used the Difference (Subtract also works) filter from Catalano framework (fork of aforgenet) to generate a image which displays the difference:

difference:

[image]

How can i "apply" (or merge) the "difference" to "image1" so that the result is "image2"?

I tried many filters using "Image Processing Lab" of aforgenet, but couldn't find the right filter.

I ask this because i have image1 on the server and get the difference from a client. Now i need to use/apply/merge the difference on image1 to get image2.

Comment: Subtract the **difference** image from the **image1**  you will get **image2**

Comment: I gave it a shot @Jeru Luke, but the result is a bit strange, i first thought it didn't work cause the change is not very visible, but the colors seem to become more a bit darker, it increase the contract it seems. I made a screenshot as illustration: http://i.imgur.com/TOmCmds.jpg . [edit] Update, it seems that "Add" instead of Subtract works, I'm only a bit puzzled about why, i'm going to do a bit more testing.

Comment: But is this what you expected to get?????????

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, I'm quite new to the subject. I was expecting image2 when i substract difference from image1. But the result of a substract is slightly a more contrasted version of image1. "Adding" (Add) the difference to image1 results in image2. (which is what i needed). Thanks for the pointer though!

Comment: Cool!!! glad I could help!!